# Cannot install Cinnamon on Debian. Is this environment compatible with it?

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, cinnamon

One year and half ago, I tried to install my new `Debian 9` computer with *Cinnamon* : it failed and froze at installation. Because I had no *Linux* knowledge I installed *Gnome* instead.

Today, I am on `Debian 10` and I did a try on an `Debian 10` VM to be safe... With Cinnamon again, and I installed it that way :

```bsh
sudo apt-get install cinnamon-desktop-environment cinnamon-l10n -y
```

1. The VM started,
2. after login a Debian wallpaper screen appeared. But it was empty : no icons, no menus, nothing.
3. Then 30 seconds after a crash message came.

Is *Cinnamon* definitely not compatible with *Debian* ?

Comment: There is an iso file for a live Debian system with Cinnamon: [debian-live-10.4.0-amd64-cinnamon.iso](https://www.debian.org/CD/live/). It works for me out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed Debian 10 in VirtualBox using default settings and everything works as expected.

Cinnamon is fully supported by Debian since it's included. You could try installing Cinnamon using `tasksel`: https://linuxhint.com/install_cinnamon_debian_10/

[image: Cinnamon in Debian 10 in VirtualBox 6.1.12]